# MySQL multilanguage select main language row if language row is emty

Tags: php, sql, database, mysqli, multilingual

Table MAIN:

```
id | main1
```

Table MAIN_LNG:

```
id | id_main | lng | desc
```

Query:

```
SELECT MAIN.*, MAIN_LNG.desc
FROM MAIN
JOIN MAIN_LNG
  ON MAIN.id = MAIN_LNG.id_main
  AND MAIN_LNG.lng = IFNULL('de', 'en')
```

Now I want to select the `de` row with de german description (`MAIN_LNG.desc`), but if this description is `NULL` then automatically select the `en` which is the main language.

How can I do it with pure `SQL`?

Answer (score 1):

[COALESCE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function returns the first non-NULL value from its arguments. All we have to do is give "de" a priority here.

```
SELECT MAIN.*, COALESCE(de.desc, en.desc) AS desc
FROM MAIN
LEFT JOIN MAIN_LNG AS de ON MAIN.id = MAIN_LNG.id_main
  AND MAIN_LNG.lng = 'de'
LEFT JOIN MAIN_LNG AS en ON MAIN.id = MAIN_LNG.id_main
  AND MAIN_LNG.lng = 'en'
```

(Haven't tested it myself.)